# Odoo 11 Website Blog color picker needed for Title and subtitle

Tags: odoo-11

I am currently working on odoo11 website blog where I want to enable color picker option for "Blog Title" and "Sub Title" how can I do so ? Can any one help in this.

[See we can edit the text but no color picker is available for the same]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztI6x.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqqw0.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do by HTML CSS Editor of website this color is apply on all blog post

See in Image
[image]

Comment: This is not a feasible solution for me at current stage I need a color picker as I have specified in a https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqqw0.png